# Best practice for saving a series of dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, database-design, series

I'm reworking some old programs and in one of them I need so save a repeating series of Dates in the database. The User picks days ranging from 1-31 and months ranging from 1-12 in a PHP-Form. Multiple Choices are possible. At least one of each must be provided.

I'll then use a daily scheduled Task to check if the value (day and month) is given and if yes - do something.

In the old system I saved it like this:

```
| Days | Months |

|1,2,5,13,15 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12|
```

Then I exploded every row in the PHP-File fired by the scheduled Task and iterated over the Array. If one of the dates is valid - do something.

What is best practice for this Use-Case? I thought about some solutions like "saving all possible Outcomes of days and months as single rows in an mapping-table" but I don't think that's an elegant solution...and it needs to be editable too after being implemented.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are right...im using MSSQL. Just added it to the tags. Also i want to get rid of the comma seperated values, that's why im rethinking this program.

Comment: Can different sets of months have different days or is it always an effectively a cross join between the array in the days column and the one in the months column?

Comment: Its always the same days for the selected months. So there is no "5th of November and 6th of December", only "5th Novemeber and December" or "6th Novemeber and December" etc. You get the idea.
But it can also be "5th and 6th of November and December".

Comment: It is definitely good idea to remove comma separated."saving all possible Outcomes of days and months as single rows in an mapping-table" is worse than comma separated.what is transaction table like ? So what exactly is requirement ?This will only tell how to store data and how to validate.what is volume of data in each table.

Comment: Suppose I store Days and month in normal manner(not comma seperated).Now what I have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at three tables.

Table one records the groups, give it a sequential group id and whatever other properties you need to record about the group of dates as a whole (requesting user id).

Second table is just group id from table one and the chosen days in rows, so each group has multiple rows.

Third table is the same as for second but for months.

When you need the final result join the second and third tables to the first on the group id. you'll automatically get a cross join between the two giving the combinations you need.

If you're expecting a large volume of data and\or a lot of repeats of the same groups then you may want to consider the possibility of re-using the groups of days and months. It will be a similar table design but tables 2 and 3 will have their own group ids and table one will have two extra columns one for day group and one for month group.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you can use a dimension-like scheme and attach day-month pairs to different entities. Suppose, the entity is called "task".

```
| tasks   |            | days     |            | months   |
| ------- |            | -------- |            | -------- |
| id_task |            | id_day   |            | id_month |
| ...     | >---M:1--- | id_month | >---M:1--- | month    |
| id_day  |            | day      |
```

Don't forget to add check constraints for `day` (1-31) and `month` (1-12) columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should expand the data in the database.  Clearly, you need a table `groups` (or something like that) with one row per group:

```
create table groups (
    group_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .  -- additional columns
);
```

Then, expand the dates for each group for the schedule:

```
create table groups_schedule (
    group_schedule_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    group_id int references groups(group_id),
    month int,
    day int
);
```

This requires multiplying out the data *in the database*.  However, I think it is a more accurate representation.  In addition, it will give you more flexibility in the future so you are not tied specifically to lists of months/days.  For instance, you might have day "25" in most months, but not December.

Comment: Isn't that the "A single row for every single possible date"-solution or do i misunderstand it? Doesn't that get pretty bloated? Like, if i need a daily schedule i have to have 366 rows for that one task for one user?

Comment: @Daniel . . . that doesn't seem like a problem to me.